# Python os.makedirs not working?

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

I wanted to make a directory for an input, if the directory did not already exist. When I run the code, it runs fine, but after entering my input, my directory is not created in the folder containing my python file. But, when I run the python code again, and enter the same value, it returns, 'Project already exists'. But no directory was actually created. I did the same thing last week and it worked fine. I have no idea why it's not working now.

```
# main.py #
import os

def create_project_dir(directory):
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    print(' Creating Project : ' + directory)
    os.makedirs(directory)

else:
    print(' Project already exists. ')

myDir = input('Dir: ')
create_project_dir(myDir)
end = input('done')
```

Comment: Are you using a *relative path*? What is the value of `os.getcwd()` when the script runs?

Comment: oh wow. C:\Windows\system32 - How do i fix this?

Comment: How would you want to handle relative paths?

Comment: I figured it out with `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))` Thank you Martijn Pieters :)